# Image from express static folder is not appearing on the client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have Node.js app, served by express, with my frontend being made with React.js. I have a static folder with images which does not appear to be reachable on the client side.

The sample path in which images are uploaded is:

`localhost:3000/public/images/avatar.jpg`

This is the code in my Node.js app, instead:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

import userRoutes from './routes/userRoutes.js';
import uploadRoutes from './routes/uploadFileRoutes.js';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());


const __dirname = path.resolve();

app.use('/public/images', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));

app.use('/', userRoutes);
app.use('/', uploadRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () =>
      console.log(`Server Running on Port: http://localhost:${PORT}`)
    )
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Here is my [backend folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL7Sq.png)

And here is my [image src path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG7zM.png) on the HTML side of the things

Any pointer/ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `path.join()` in this case, just use `__dirname` and append the remainder of the path.

The below syntax should work for you:

```
app.use('/public/images',express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
```

Also, I see that you have specified the value of `__dirname`. You don't have to, it is an **environment** *variable*, that by itself contains the absolute path of the directory in which your file is being executed.

Try removing the statement:

`const __dirname = path.resolve()`

Comment: Noted, but still the images is not displaying. the url result is http://localhost:3000/public/images/avatar-1614443533456.png

Comment: Is that .png or .jpeg? Just to make sure, rename your pictures so something unequivocable like `a.jpeg`, so we know it's not a spelling mistake

Comment: It might as well be because you have assigned a value to `__dirname`. I have updated my answer, please let me know if it works.

Comment: I already remove the const __dirname. I also check the network on the on the devtool the status code of the url is 304. The problem is when i click the link it will redirect me to the homepage of my app. but the url is the url of the image.

Comment: Ok, if that is the case you can try putting your app.use() for the static folder before the other app.use() statements to begin with. If it does not help could you please post your relevant index.js code

Comment: The code above is already updated. But still the react homepage is the one that been rendered

Comment: I have just seen that you have `app.use('/public/images', express.static('/public/images'));`, but express.static() needs an abspath, like the earlier example: `app.use('/public/images',express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));`

Comment: I also did that but still the error is the same. I also attach an image of the result

Comment: I have reconstrusted your entire code and it actually works for me. At this point, the only differences there are, are in your `userRoutes` and `uploadRoutes`, as well as the mongoose connections. Does anything happen if you comment out those `app.use()` statements, or if you remove the mongoose connection as a conditional for the port listening?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I see you've accepted my answer, I guess you managed to have it working with what can both we see eventually. Have a good day and happy coding